# Failed SD Card file expand on Raspberry Pi

Tags: sd-card, linux, filesystem

I´m trying to expand an SD that´s running on a Raspberry Pi. The original SD was 8Gb. I saved it to PC with Win32DiskImager, then wrote a new 32Gb SD from that image, and run the file expand option in raspi-config.  The total size is still in the 8Gb area.

This is the SSH output after running raspi-config:

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 28.9 GiB, 31016878080 bytes, 60579840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9a7af20d

Device         Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192   532479   524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      532480 60579839 60047360 28.6G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): Partition number (1,2, default 2):
Partition 2 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): Partition type
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): Partition number (2-4, default 2): First sector (2048-60579839, default 2048): Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (532480-60579839, default 60579839):
Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux' and of size 28.6 GiB.
Partition #2 contains a ext4 signature.

Command (m for help):
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 28.9 GiB, 31016878080 bytes, 60579840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9a7af20d

Device         Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192   532479   524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      532480 60579839 60047360 28.6G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
```

My **df -h** looks like this (I have a 1.5Gb RAM disk):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       6.8G  4.5G  2.0G  69% /
devtmpfs        779M     0  779M   0% /dev
tmpfs           908M     0  908M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           908M  8.6M  900M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           908M     0  908M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.5G  8.0K  1.5G   1% /home/x1/dh2sg/fsram
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   54M  199M  22% /boot
tmpfs           182M     0  182M   0% /run/user/1001
```

I have tried:

**# cd /boot**
**# sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2**

which gives me:

```
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Filesystem at /dev/mmcblk0p2 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 2
resize2fs: Permission denied to resize filesystem
```

so I-ve tried:

**# sudo umount -l /dev/mmcblk0p2**

**# resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2**

which returns:

```
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
ext2fs_check_mount_point: Can't check if filesystem is mounted due to missing mtab file while determining whether /dev/mmcblk0p2 is mounted.
```

As far as I can see, mtab is there:

```
$ ls -lrt /etc/mtab
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Aug 20  2020 /etc/mtab -> ../proc/self/mounts

$ ls -lrt /proc/mounts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Oct 16 19:21 /proc/mounts -> self/mounts
```

and this the full contents of /etc/mtab:

```
/dev/root / ext4 rw,noatime 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=797592k,nr_inodes=103885,mode=755 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup/unified cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd 0 0
none /sys/fs/bpf bpf rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=31,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0
sunrpc /run/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw,relatime 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /home/x1/dh2sg/fsram tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1536000k 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1001 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=185936k,mode=700,uid=1001,gid=1001 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1001/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1001,group_id=1001 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you reboot? Although no one can say if you use Win32DiskImager; try using a supported method.

Comment: @Milliways -- yes, rebooted many times. What would be a supported method? My case is that I started working with an 8Gb SD card, and then moved to a 32Gb card. As the 8Gb card has a lot of fine tuning, my approach was to do an image file of the 8Gb card and then write that image to the 32Gb card (and of course use 100% of the 32Gb space). How would you do that? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running `raspi-config` then select `Advanced Options` - first choice should be `Expand Filesystem`

Comment: @Bravo: yes, as said in the question, that´s the first thing I´ve done. Thanks!

Comment: oh, sorry, I missed that @PiBer2

Answer (score 1):

I see the partition is already resized, all you have to do is to run `resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2` as root. This should be done on a mounted partition, unmounting / on a running system is a sure way to crash it.

If `resize2fs` fails to grow the partition even as root, it's typically because you have errors on it which need to be fixed with `fsck`. If this is the case, running `dmesg` after a failed `resize2fs` attempt will output something like:

> kernel: EXT4-fs warning: There are errors in the filesystem, so online resizing is not allowed

It's possible that `umount -l /` caused the inconsistencies in the first place.

Note that it's actually possible to unmount the / on a running system if you really have to (e.g. you need to shrink it instead of growing), but it's somewhat more [complicated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226872/106927) than just `umount -l /`: you need to stop most system services, create a new minimal root file system on `tmpfs` and switch to it using `pivot_root`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry... Yes, I have that output from dmesg.  I guess I will have to begin from scratch with a new SD!

Answer (score 0):

There are literally dozens of approaches; the most conventional is using `dd` although probably not for Windows.

**SD Card Copier** copies on the Pi itself and automatically adjusts size.

Various [options](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/104644/8697) are discussed.

The procedure I use (which is fast and efficient) [Backup image of SD Card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103991/8697) makes a small installable image, but takes more setup. (I use this to make regular backups.)

[can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28087/8697) looks at other options.